# Navigate through a list repeatedly calling a global function each time passing 3 objects

Tags: c++, list, loops, object, stl

So i hard coded in some obejcts, here is the class,

```
class Point // class point will have an x and a y value 
{
public:
// should contain attributes of a single point 
double x ; // x value
double y ; //y value
double f ; //importance factor

//constructor
Point (double xpoint, double ypoint)// can accept two agruments
{
    x = xpoint ;
    y = ypoint ;
}

//default constructor 
Point ()
{
    x = 7;
    y = 8;
}

//set methods
void setX (double pointx)
{
    x = pointx;
}

void setY (double pointy)
{
    y = pointy ;
}

void setF(double inF)
{
    f = inF ;
}

//get methods for retyening values to main
double getX()
{
    return x; // return the X form the setX
}

double getY ()
{
    return y ; // return the y from the setY
}

//return the importance factor
double getF ()
{
    return f ;
}
```

};

and manually added them to a template list

```
Point point1 (7,5); // new point object point1 with value x=2.5, y=5.3
Point point2 (4,8); // second point obejct 
Point point3 (8,9); // third point object
Point point4 (10,5);//fourth point object
Point point5 (6,8);//fifth point
Point point6 (4,7);//point 6


list<Point>pointList ; // stl list that will contain my objects.
pointList.push_back(point1);//adds the obejcts to the list from the back each time {point1}
pointList.push_back(point2);//{point1, point2} < point2 pushed_back
pointList.push_back(point3);//{point, point}
pointList.push_back(point4);
pointList.push_back(point5);
pointList.push_back(point6);
```

Navigate through the list repeatedly calling the global function calculatef each time passing 3 objects so that all objects get assigned an f value
here is the caclulate f method

```
//global fucntion that takes three objects as arguments 
static void calculateF (Point& p1, Point& p2, Point& p3)// point2 needs to be a     reference otherwise f is just changed locally. 
{
    double F ; // i now have an f in the class and in the method? do i need both?

    double xPoint1 = p1.getX(); // x value of object p1
    double yPoint1 = p1.getY(); // y value of object p1
    double xPoint2 = p2.getX(); // x value of object p2
    double yPoint2 = p2.getY(); // y coordinates of object p2 
    double xPoint3 = p3.getX(); // x coordinates of obejct p3
    double yPoint3 = p3.getY(); // y coorinates of obejct p3

    //equation for working out f from these six values
    //temp variables to store the length of the triangles sides.
    double p2p3 = sqrt (((xPoint2 - xPoint3)*(xPoint2 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint2 - yPoint3)*(yPoint2 - yPoint3))); //length point2 to point1 (PR in assingment notes)
    cout << "p1p2 is = " << p2p3 << endl; // print the value of p2p3 (PR) 
    double p1p2 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint2)*(xPoint1 - xPoint2)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint2)*(yPoint1 - yPoint2))); //length point1 to point 2 (LP in assingment notes)
    cout << "p1p2 is = " << p1p2 << endl;
    double p1p3 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint3)*(xPoint1 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint3)*(yPoint1 - yPoint3)));//length of point1 to point 3 (LR in assigment notes) 
    cout << "hypotenuse p1p3 is = " << p1p3 << endl; 

    F = p1p2 + p2p3 - p1p3 ; //equation for f
    cout << "importance factor is " << F << endl ;
    p2.setF(F); //  setting F to f in class 
}
```

The only way i have been able to use the method so far is by passing the obejcts 3 at a time not using the list like (point1,point2,point3) etc. This is no good as i need to find the point with the lowest f value and remove it form the list. then recalculate the f values again and repeat this process until the points have been reduced to a user specified amount. So as the points need to be reduced so does the lists size, so i need navigate the list each time passing three obejcts to the method. I hope the question is long winded, i just wanted to gove an overview of the whole program.

to summarise i need to navigate through a list passing three objects to a global method each time

Many thanks

edit: Please guys, ive been at this for days and none of the help so far is quite what i need.. or i need more information on them

code now reads

```
using namespace std ;

class Point // class point will have an x and a y value 
{
public:
// should contain attributes of a single point 
double x ; // x value
double y ; //y value
double f ; //importance factor

//constructor
Point (double xpoint, double ypoint)// can accept two agruments
{
    x = xpoint ;
    y = ypoint ;
}

//default constructor 
Point ()
{
    x = 7;
    y = 8;
}

//set methods
void setX (double pointx)
{
    x = pointx;
}

void setY (double pointy)
{
    y = pointy ;
}

void setF(double inF)
{
    f = inF ;
}

//get methods for retyening values to main
double getX()
{
    return x; // return the X form the setX
}

double getY ()
{
    return y ; // return the y from the setY
}

//return the importance factor
double getF ()
{
    return f ;
}
```

};

```
//global fucntion that takes three objects as arguments 
static void calculateF (Point& p1, Point& p2, Point& p3)// point2 needs to be a reference otherwise f is just changed locally.
```

{
            double F ;

```
double xPoint1 = p1.getX(); // x value of object p1
double yPoint1 = p1.getY(); // y value of object p1
double xPoint2 = p2.getX(); // x value of object p2
double yPoint2 = p2.getY(); // y coordinates of object p2 
double xPoint3 = p3.getX(); // x coordinates of obejct p3
double yPoint3 = p3.getY(); // y coorinates of obejct p3

//equation for working out f from these six values
//temp variables to store the length of the triangles sides.
double p2p3 = sqrt (((xPoint2 - xPoint3)*(xPoint2 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint2 - yPoint3)*(yPoint2 - yPoint3))); //length point2 to point1 (PR in assingment notes)
//cout << "p1p2 is = " << p2p3 << endl; // print the value of p2p3 (PR) 
double p1p2 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint2)*(xPoint1 - xPoint2)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint2)*(yPoint1 - yPoint2))); //length point1 to point 2 (LP in assingment notes)
//cout << "p1p2 is = " << p1p2 << endl;
double p1p3 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint3)*(xPoint1 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint3)*(yPoint1 - yPoint3)));//length of point1 to point 3 (LR in assigment notes) 
//cout << "hypotenuse p1p3 is = " << p1p3 << endl; 

F = p1p2 + p2p3 - p1p3 ; //equation for f
p2.setF(F);
//cout << "importance factor is " << p2.getF() << endl ;
//p2.setF(F); //  setting F to f in class
```

}

int main ()
{
    int userPoints ;

```
cout << "This program will reduce the number of points in shape X to a user defined amount " << endl;
cout << "Enter the number of points you wish this shape to be reduced to:  " << endl ;
cin >> userPoints ;
cout << "this shape will be reduced to: " <<userPoints << " points." << endl;
// create objects of type Point, passing different x and y values to the contructor

Point point1 (1,1); // new point object point1 with value x=2.5, y=5.3
Point point2 (2,2); // second point obejct 
Point point3 (3,3); // third point object
Point point4 (4,4);//fourth point object
Point point5 (5,5);//fifth point
Point point6 (6,6);//point 6



list<Point>pointList ; // stl list that will contain my objects.
//pointList.push_back(point6);//duplicate point
pointList.push_back(point1);//adds the obejcts to the list from the back each time {point1}
pointList.push_back(point2);//{point1, point2} < point2 pushed_back
pointList.push_back(point3);//{point, point}
pointList.push_back(point4);
pointList.push_back(point5);
pointList.push_back(point6);
//pointList.push_back(point1);//duplicate point
//add objects to the list


//while lists size is > user points
list<Point>::iterator it1(pointList.begin()), it2(pointList.begin()), it3(pointList.begin()); // 3 iterators all originally pointing to beginning of list
if (it1 != pointList.end()) { ++it2; ++it3; }
if (it2 != pointList.end()) { ++it3; }

int cnt = 1;

do {
     calculateF(*it1, *it2, *it3);

    cout << it1->x << " " << it1->y << " -- ";
    cout << it2->x << " " << it2->y << " -- ";
    cout << it3->x << " " << it3->y << endl;
    cout << "Calc step done " << cnt << "  f is" << it1->f << endl ;
    ++it1;
    ++it2;
    ++it3;

    if ( it1 == pointList.end()) it1=pointList.begin();
    if ( it2 == pointList.end()) it2=pointList.begin();
    if ( it3 == pointList.end()) it3=pointList.begin();
    cnt++;
} while ( it1 != pointList.begin());

/*
while (it3 != pointList.end())
{
   calculateF(*it1, *it2, *it3);
   ++it1;
   ++it2;
   ++it3;
}
*/


//remove smallest f and repeat


/*
list<Point>::iterator pI ;
 //iterator initially points to beginning of list

for (pI = pointList.begin() ; pI!=pointList.end() ; pI++)
{
    cout << *pI ;
}
*/

// calculateF fucntion on point 2
//calculateF(point1, point2, point3);
//calculateF(point2, point3, point4);
//calculateF(point3,point4, point5);
//calculateF(point4,point5,point6);
//point2.getF();
//cout << "point 2 has f value of: " << point2.getF() << endl ;

system ("PAUSE");
return 0 ;
```

}

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking us to make an algorithm for you?

Comment: No, ive just hit a block and am inexperienced with lists and iterators. I dont know how to use the iterator to traverse the list each time removing the lowest point. Something like while list.size>userInput, calculate F for all points, compare F values to find lowest, remove this point and repeat. I think im getting confused by the iterators.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a vector instead of a list you can use the iterator over the list with the + operator which enables you to simply write that:

```
vector<Point> pointList ; 
pointList.push_back(point1);
pointList.push_back(point2);
pointList.push_back(point3);
pointList.push_back(point4);
pointList.push_back(point5);
pointList.push_back(point6);

if ( pointList.size() >= 3)
{
    vector<Point>::iterator it = pointList.begin();
    for ( it = pointList.begin(); (it+2) != pointList.end(); it++) 
    {   
        calculateF( *it, *(it+1), *(it+2));
    }
}
```

// code stolen from Nikos answer to comment it because OP wants to know how it works :-)

```
// create 3 iterators which points to the first element of the list
list<Point>::iterator it1(pointList.begin());
list<Point>::iterator it2(pointList.begin());
list<Point>::iterator it3(pointList.begin());

// now we have the 3 iterators, the it2 should point on 2. element of list 
// and the it3 should point to the 3. list element.
// An iterator simply points to the next element if we do '++' operation on
// the iterator. Here the syntax and semantic is the same as for "normal" pointers,
// but it works also for list iterators. The ++operator for a list iterator 
// itself knows how to get to the next list element. The iterator ++operator knows
// that there is a link in the list element which is pointing to the next list 
// element. So simple so easy :-)

if (it1 != pointList.end()) { ++it2; ++it3; }
// now it2 points to second element
// and it3 points also to second element

if (it2 != pointList.end()) { ++it3; }
// and now it3 points to the 3. element. Fine!

// now we start a loop, until the it3 points not to the end() of the list.
// any container define end() which is exact the element BEHIND the last valid element
// inside a list. If a list contains 10 elements, end() points to the 11.! which
// is not there and must not be accessed through the iterator!
while (it3 != pointList.end())
{   
    // now we call your function with p1,p2,p3 in the first step
    calculateF(*it1, *it2, *it3); 

    // after that, we set each iterator to the next element
    // it2 -> 2
    // it3 -> 3
    // it4 -> 4
    ++it1;
    ++it2;
    ++it3;

    and run the loop again, until it3 points to end()
}
```

I think you should read about iterators in c++. Using a native array will not help if you want to erase elements somewhere in the array.

EDIT3: to do a round robin loop:

```
int cnt = 1;

do {
    calculateF(*it1, *it2, *it3);

    cout << it1->x << " " << it1->y << " -- ";
    cout << it2->x << " " << it2->y << " -- ";
    cout << it3->x << " " << it3->y << endl;
    cout << "Calc step done " << cnt << "  f is" << it1->f << endl ;
    ++it1;
    ++it2;
    ++it3;

    if ( it1 == pointList.end()) it1=pointList.begin();
    if ( it2 == pointList.end()) it2=pointList.begin();
    if ( it3 == pointList.end()) it3=pointList.begin();
    cnt++;
} while ( it1 != pointList.begin());
```

It is not valid to add the first 2 elements to the end. This can result it quite complex results while removing and calculating f in these objects. It is never a good idea to have something doubled only for bad designed algorithms :-)

But the loop should do the job now.

EDIT again:
I removed your output, changed all point values to 1) 1,1 2) 2,2 and so on and the output is that:

```
1 1 -- 2 2 -- 3 3
Calc step done 1  f is0
2 2 -- 3 3 -- 4 4
Calc step done 2  f is0
3 3 -- 4 4 -- 5 5
Calc step done 3  f is0
4 4 -- 5 5 -- 6 6
Calc step done 4  f is0
5 5 -- 6 6 -- 1 1
Calc step done 5  f is0
6 6 -- 1 1 -- 2 2
Calc step done 6  f is2.82843
```

I don't know what you are calculating but the loop seems to work :-)

Comment: Hi Klaus, thanks for your response. Will using vectors be ok? as i need to recalculate the f for each point each time i find and remove the point with the lowest f value. So at the end of finding all the F values i need to find the point with the lowest F value. All this will be done while list.size is > user input kinda thing

Comment: a list is better if elements will be removed frequently. In the opposite a list requires more space for the links to the next object. So simply use the code from Nikos. It will fit your needs :-)

Comment: well elements are going to be frequently removed as i might have 500 points to be reduced to 10 for example. Ok i will try and get some more information from Niko,thanks very much for your time

Comment: friend. i dont understand Nikos answer. can you help?

Comment: can i ditch the stl all togther and use an array? as im clearly not getting this

Comment: I hope my edit help you understanding the code. But you should learn about containers and iterators.

Comment: thanks alot for your time Klaus. I editted the list to include a duplicate of the last element at the front of the list and the first element of list at the end to make sure all elements get an F value calculated. The comments are helping me understand what the iterators are doing. Now i need to compare all the f values, so find the smallest F value. do i need another iterator for that too friend? many thanks

Comment: Excellent commenting in this answer. @punity "can i ditch the stl all together and use an array" just because you don't understand this is a _backwards_ step.

Comment: Not only backwards. It could never work, because he must delete elements in the list. In case of an array this means a lot of copy actions. A lot work for nothing. A list is the perfect solution!

Comment: That edit almost works, point one seems to return a memory address however. The others seem to calculate correctly.

Comment: I add my output to the example code. It seems to work. I will stop here and I hope now is payday :-)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put in to try and help me. But Why did you have do change the point values, it needs to work with any point values, no matter what the values are the first point doesnt return an actual number. Im really sorry, i dont know what to say. The first solution with duplicate points made more sense to me

Comment: I changed the point values to see which elements are accessed. As you can see from the output, it got the correct order and the full set. The rest is not up to the loop algo, it is up to your calculation. Maybe you have a copy and paste error :-)

Comment: i changed my points too, the poutput is still the same Klaus. the first point is actually calclating point 2 as its the middle number being passed.

Comment: I can't catch your problem. Can you describe the problem a bit more in detail? The debug output shows that the iterators are passed correctly. SO tells me that we should stop discussing in comments :-)

Comment: I dont have enough rep to move to chat :( there is no errors but the output for the first point is not correct it outputs 11-22-33 calc step done 1 f is -9.25596+e061